# Silex Middleware Authentication Works differently in Postman and in Browser

Tags: php, angular, authentication, middleware, silex

I am not an experienced back-end developer so this question might not be the right question, but the problem is real!

I am using Silex as a simple backend for an Angular 2 App, I have a middleware that checks if user provided a JWT token.

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app)  {
// Checks if the credential header is provided
if (!$token = $request->headers->get('X-BEARER-TOKEN')) {
    return new Response('Bad Request', 400);
}

$data = $app['user.validateToken']($token); // This checks if the JWT token is valid

if(!$data || (int) $data['user_role_id'] != 2){
    return new Response('Access Denied', 403);
}
});
```

and I have an API endpoint that returns some stuff, let's say Dashboard information.

```
$app->get('/dashboard', function () use ($app) {

$stmnt = $app['db']->executeQuery(
    "SELECT Query"
);
$result = $stmnt->fetchAll();

if($result === false) {
    return new Response('Not Found', 404);
}else{
    $result = array('message' => 'success', 'status' => 200, 'data' => $result);
    return $app->json($result, 200);
}
});
```

This does not work and I get a "Bad Request" because the Request cannot pick up Header Data.

Puzzling notes:
A - The code above works well if I call the API from Postman, but when I call the API from browser (in this case an Angular app) I get a Bad Request.

B - If I move the credential logic from before-middleware to the endpoint (The code below) everything works well from Postman calls and app calls.

```
$app->get('/dashboard', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

// Checks if the credential header is provided
if (!$token = $request->headers->get('X-BEARER-TOKEN')) {
    return new Response('Bad Request', 400);
}

$data = $app['user.validateToken']($token);

if(!$data || (int) $data['user_role_id'] != 2){
    return new Response('Access Denied', 403);
}

$stmnt = $app['db']->executeQuery(
    "SELECT Query"
);
$result = $stmnt->fetchAll();

if($result === false) {
    return new Response('Not Found', 404);
}else{

    $result = array_map('intval', $result[0]);

    $result = array('message' => 'success', 'status' => 200, 'data' => $result);
    return $app->json($result, 200);
}

});
```

Any idea what is it that I'm missing?

*BTW in order to make the preflight CORS OPTIONS work I have the following code attached to the end of the app, I'm not sure if it is related to the problem or not.*

```
$app->match("{url}", function($url) use ($app){
    return "OK";
})->assert('url', '.*')->method("OPTIONS");
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem, which was silly, IMO,

The issue was that application lifecycle was not considered correctly,
$app->before runs BEFORE $app->options, therefore when browsers asks if the OPTIONS header is acceptable, ->before lifecycle does not know what to do with it.

Adding following code to ->before solved the issue:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'OPTIONS') {
    return new Response(null, 204);
}
```

Of course this renders ->options and ->match obsolete, which is still funky. Probably what I did is just a workaround not a solution after all.